# DbContext instance used in two places concurrently - EF - Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, hangfire

I'm using EF Core and [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to run a recurring job. Hangfire seems to be causing the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
> completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same
> instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading
> issues with DbContext

And.. I'm not sure why. I register the EF context as follows:

```
services 
    .AddDbContext<PaymentContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString),
    ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

And then..

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
   
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => myService.ExecuteMyJob(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Where myService has been injected into the `Startup.Configure` function, and myService contains the reference to the `DbContext`. Which is transient in theory, and so shouldn't be shared by the service and other places.

However the stacktrace leads here:

```
var plans = _context.Plan
                .Include(pp => pp.PlanItem)
                .Where(pp => pp.PolicyId == policyId)
                .ToList() // materialise query
                .OrderBy(pp => pp.PlanItem.First().Date)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: What are the details of your `ExecuteMyJob()`? (void, Task, async)

Comment: All your Hangfire jobs must create a new Dependency Scope, done with `IServiceProvider.CreateScope`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create scope for your dependency.

```
public class Job
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    
    public Job(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void ExecuteJob()
    {
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var databaseContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `IServiceProvider`, you need `IServiceScopeFactory` (`IServiceProvider.CreateScope()` is actually an extension method that resolves `IServiceScopeFactory` and calls `CreateScope()`). But even after that you are implementing **Service Locator Anti-Pattern**. I'd recommend implementing [this approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185497/using-iservicescopefactory-without-implementing-the-service-locator-pattern/238506#238506) to avid anti patterns.